# Search View with my custom adapter

Tags: java, android, searchview, custom-adapter, notesview

i am trying to make a search view with this adapter:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
/**
 * Wrapper para notas. Util para cambiar el fondo de los item seleccionados.
 */
Paint paint = new Paint();
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_CATID = "id";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes_schema-v%s.sql";
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private ArrayList<NotesAdapter.NoteViewWrapper> notesData;
public Context context;


public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}

public static class NoteViewWrapper {

    private final Note note;
    private boolean isSelected;

    /**
     * Contruye un nuevo NoteWrapper con la nota dada.
     *
     * @param note una nota.
     */
    public NoteViewWrapper(Note note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Note getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}

private static final DateFormat DATETIME_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM);

private final List<NoteViewWrapper> data;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param data la lista de notas a usar como fuente de datos para este adaptador.
 */
public NotesAdapter(List<NoteViewWrapper> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

/**
 * @return cuantos datos hay en la lista de notas.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

/**
 * @param position la posición de la nota que se quiere
 * @return la nota en la posición dada.
 */
@Override
public NoteViewWrapper getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

/**
 * @param position una posición
 * @return la misma posición dada
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) { // inflar componente visual
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notes_row, parent, false);
        //CardView cardsView = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_cardboard);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); // ya existe, solo es reciclarlo
    // Inicializa la vista con los datos de la nota
    NoteViewWrapper noteViewWrapper = data.get(position);
    holder.noteIdText.setText(String.valueOf(noteViewWrapper.note.getId()));
    holder.noteTitleText.setText(noteViewWrapper.note.getTitle());
    // se la nota è più di 80 caratteri"..."
    holder.noteContentText.setText(noteViewWrapper.note.getContent().length() >= 80 ? noteViewWrapper.note.getContent().substring(0, 80).concat("...") : noteViewWrapper.note.getContent());
    holder.noteDateText.setText(DATETIME_FORMAT.format(noteViewWrapper.note.getUpdatedAt()));
    // Cambia il colore se la nota è cliccata
    if (noteViewWrapper.isSelected) {
        CardView cardsView = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_cardboard);
        // sfondo grigio quando nota selezionata
        cardsView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cacaca"));
        //cardsView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.drawable.statelist_item_background);
        //cardsView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_note);
        //holder.parent.setBackgroundColor(parent.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_note));
        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        //   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    } else {
        CardView cardsView = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_cardboard);
        // sfondo bianco quando nota non selezionata
        cardsView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        //holder.parent.setBackgroundColor(parent.getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }
    return convertView;
}


/**
 * Almacena componentes visuales para acceso rápido sin necesidad de buscarlos muy seguido.
 */
private static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView noteIdText;
    private TextView noteTitleText;
    private TextView noteContentText;
    private TextView noteDateText;

    private View parent;

    /**
     * Constructor. Encuentra todas los componentes visuales en el componente padre dado.
     *
     * @param parent un componente visual.
     */
    private ViewHolder(View parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        noteIdText = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.note_id);
        noteTitleText = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        noteContentText = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.note_content);
        noteDateText = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.note_date);
    }
}}
```

I am quite new and i don't know how can i do it...so i can not do it.
Can anyone help me?

Currently i have:

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            //Do some magic
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            //Do some magic
        }
    });
```

More info: https://github.com/Heromine/Service-Notes

Answer (score 0):

Please add a public method like filter(String searchText) in adapter class;

> ```
> private ArrayList<NotesAdapter.NoteViewWrapper> notesData;
> ```
>
> Make a copy of these ArrayList
>
> add all item to copied ArrayList

```
public void filter(String charItem) {
  String searchItem = charItem.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault);
  notesData.remove();
  if(searchItem.length()<0){
     notesData.addAll(copyList);
  } else{
    for(myItem item : copyList){
      if(item.name.contines(searchItem){
         notesData.add(item);
      }
    }
  notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Call these function from your SearchView onQueryTextChaged(){} method and pass the value.

Comment: will this work with the sqlite? and what should be myItem?

Comment: yes.actually you are loading data from sqlite so it would come with list of object,myItem i just specified as your model(Object) class. contine data

Comment: Could you make a pull request? Because in my way is not working

Comment: Also what is the remove method? please a pull request may really help me

Comment: The remove method is use for removing items from the Array